# How to create a site based on custom web template ID not Name or title

Tags: 2013

How can I create a site using custom web template using c# and templates name and id in SharePoint 2013 ? I don't want to use web template title.

Comment: I know you are asking about 2013, but it is the same idea as for 2010

Comment: updated my quessttion

Comment: Why would you not use GUID + Name as all other people do? :)

Comment: can we get example plzz thankyou

Comment: Do you want a web or a site collection created?

Comment: For web you see the method, and the code example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412285.aspx

Comment: i need example of where people using GUID + Name for find a web template and creating one with it plzz